# Listings: Package keyval Error: consecutivenumbers

Tags: errors, listings, code

The following MWE, taken straight from the `listings` documentation, produces the error `Package keyval Error: consecutivenumbers undefined.`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    numbers=left,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={},
    linerange={1-2,6-7},
    consecutivenumbers=false]
Line no. 1
Line no. 2
Line no. 3
Line no. 4
Line no. 5
Line no. 6
Line no. 7
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The output should be:

[image]

What causes this error and how can I achieve similar output (with listings or otherwise)?

Comment: Which version of the `listings` package do you use?

Comment: @leandriis The version was 1.8c 2019-09-10. Updating to 1.8d fixed the issue. Thanks for the reminder.